# Javascript: Getting values out of an XML file with weird formatting (Recursion?)

Tags: javascript, xml, recursion

I'm trying to iterate through an XML file that has weird formatting (I used pdftohtml to make the xml file and the output I get is weird but it's more usable than outputting to HTML)

Here's an example:

```
<text height="11" font="3">Lastname1, Firstname1</text>
<text height="11" font="3">111111-1</text>
<text height="6" font="2">random text</text>
<text height="6" font="2">random text</text>
<text height="11" font="3">Lastname2, Firstname2</text>
<text height="11" font="3">222222-2</text>
<text height="6" font="2">random text</text>
<text height="6" font="2">random text</text>
<text height="11" font="3">Lastname3, Firstname3</text>
<text height="11" font="3">name3long</text>
<text height="11" font="3">333333-3</text>
<text height="6" font="2">random text</text>
<text height="6" font="2">random text</text>
<text height="11" font="3">Lastname4, Firstname4</text>
<text height="11" font="3">444444-4</text>
<text height="11" font="3">Lastname5, Firstname5</text>
<text height="11" font="3">555555-5</text>
<text height="11" font="3">Lastname6, Firstname6</text>
<text height="11" font="3">name6long</text>
<text height="11" font="3">666666-3</text>
```

To break it down.  The Name block starts with the name with attributes of height: 11, font: 3 and ends with the ID that has the same attributes but it is always length: 8.

I thought recursion would solve my problem but it doesn't give me the output I want as I'm trying to get the line numbers of where the name block starts and where it ends.

Here's a sample of the code I'm using

```
var txt = xml.getElementsByTagName('text');

    function block(b){
        var line = txt[b];
        if(line.innerHTML.length == 8){
            return b;
        }
        else{
            block(b+1);
        }
    }


    function getNameBlock(){

        // Notes: Name and Employee ID has attributes of height: 11 and font: 3
        // Employee ID has always length: 8;
        //
        // Start value should be assigned when we hit the attributes of height: 11, left: 62, font: 3
        // End value should be assigned when we hit the attributes above as well as length: 8
        // Console output will be start and end values

        for(var i=0;i<txt.length;i++){
            var line = txt[i];
            var start;
            var end;
            if(line.getAttribute('height') == '11' &&  line.getAttribute('font') == 3){
                start = i;
                end = block(start)

                console.log("Start: "+start+" End: "+end);

            }

        }
    }
```

My output isn't working the way I want it to because it gives me:

```
Start: 0 End: undefined
Start: 1 End: 1
Start: 4 End: undefined
Start: 5 End: 5
etc....
```

Am I just trying to complicate things with recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Block function you have to return value in else statement

```js
function block(b){
        var line = txt[b];
        if(line.innerHTML.length == 8){
            return b;
        }
        else{
        //if(b+1>=txt.length) return "Out Of Range"
           return block(b+1); // you missed return here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Suhail! I've been trying to decipher the XML all night and this really helps me a lot!

Comment: @primetimeCanuck You are welcome, I know that this solution may not be the ideal solution , but I hope it will help you